# Sass lint task in Gulp - Code quality

Tags: sass, less, lint, gulp, recess

I recently moved to Sass in a side project with Gulp. I'm used to LESS development and I'm finding hard to find some tools:

I want to keep a minimum **code quality watcher** in my project since we are more than one developer writting Sass (not only a linter for syntax errors)

- I used to do it with recess for LESS >
  https://github.com/twitter/recess
- Or in Grunt, a quality code linter for Sass (grunt-scss-lint) >
  https://github.com/ahmednuaman/grunt-scss-lint

What I'm trying to do is to set some **quality code options** like: maximum nesting depth, noIds, using dashes for classes...etc.

Is there any tool in Gulp for code linting?

Comment: As a workaround I'm using gulp-csslint but there should be a tool for linting before compiling > https://github.com/lazd/gulp-csslint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no resources for linting SCSS in gulp yet so, with the help of my colleague Juanfran, we can finally lint our sass code with this **gulp-scss-linter**

[Gulp plugin to validate `.scss` files with `scss-lint`](https://github.com/juanfran/gulp-scss-lint)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use [Gulp Sass Lint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass-lint) npm package.
2. You can also use [Sass Lint Auto Fix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-lint-auto-fix) npm package with the above package which will fixes lint errors.

Comment: gulp-sass-lint is currently unmaintained. https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint